# Updating Xcode 4.3 to use a more recent Clang

Tags: clang, xcode4.3, llvm-clang

How can I configure Xcode 4.3.2 to use the tip-of-trunk Clang (or any Clang later than the Clang shipped with Xcode 4.3.2)?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Python script set-xcode-analyzer bundled with the releases at http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/installation. But note that this may depend on the version(s) of Python you’ve got installed: http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=11661